# How to track unique open from a Simplenews Newsletter?

Tags: google-analytics, drupal-7

I send newsletters from my Drupal-7 website and I want to track how many unique users opened the newsletter. I added the tracking pixel code which is the following:

```
<img src="http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&amp;tid=test;1&amp;cid=123445678&amp;t=event&amp;ec=email&amp;ea=open_test_newsletter&amp;el=recipient_id&amp;cs=newsletter&amp;cm=email&amp;cn=Campaign_Name">
```

and the I check the events action from my Google Analytics account for the open_test_newsletter attribute. But this code doesn't show uniqueness and I don't get good results for the success of my campaign.
Is there a better way to achieve uniqueness or am I missing something at  Google Analytics functions?

Comment: Do you use the same client id (cid parameter) for all newsletters ? Because the client id is what tells users apart, if you use the same in every email all will be attributed to the same person. Plus Webmail clients cache images, so this method is not completely accurate.

Comment: The truth is that I only change the open attribute, because I don't know how this works. So, which is the best method?

Comment: This probably _is_ the best method, even if it's not accurate. You need to change the cid parameter to something that is unique per user to get unique counts.

Comment: But I add one code per newsletter and it's sent at 50.000 users. You suggest that I add 50.000 tracking pixels at my newsletters code?

Comment: No, I suggest you add one Pixel with a placeholder that is dynamically replaced per user. That's how almost all newsletter software works. I would be amazed if Drupal would not allow to set personalized fields.

Comment: Oh, I see...Do you have an example available or a page where I can see the code implemented? I am quite a new developer and it's the first time I use google analytics.

Comment: I'm afraid that is specific to the newsletter software in question, so I cannot really help with Drupal (most commercial software has dynamic placeholders baked in so one does not have to worry about how to implement this oneself).

Comment: Thanks a lot!you helped me understand better the aspect of  the newsletter and it open!